# NodeJS send string

Tags: sockets, node.js, buffer

As I see Node JS can't send string to client.
When I use `socket.write("string")` client doesn't receive anything. `socket.write(new Buffer("string"))` — same situation.

```js
var b = new Buffer(15);
b.write("string");
socket.write(b);
```

It looks like something works, but client receives string along with a lot of blank space.

```js
var b = new Buffer(6); //6 - lenght of string in bytes
b.write("string");
socket.write(b);
```

Again nothing!

```js
var b = new Buffer(7);
b.write("string");
socket.write(b);
```

Now there's less blank characters.
My head really hurts. Is it really complicated to send simple string?
Waiting for my savior :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`socket.write("string")` actually works fine. Check [the docs](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_write_data_encoding_callback).

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to end the transmission, after each write do a [`socket.end();`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_end_data_encoding)

Also, if you're only sending one string you can always do a [`socket.end(stringToSend);`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_end_data_encoding)

Please also refer to [NodeJS documentation of the modul 'net'](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html).

Comment: Huh? Why end? I'm developing browser MMO. So every sent message should disconnect user from server?

Comment: when you do a socket.end(), it ends the current message, doesn't disconnect the socket, it just tells the client-side that the message being sent in that section is the last one in that batch.